# What is an example of monotonically decelerating/accelerating function?

Tags: functions

I came across the term monotonically decelerating function. How can it be written as a mathematical function?

Comment: I've never heard of "decelerating" functions, but I suppose it is just a way to say $y''<0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the simple case where an object moves along a $1$-dimensional axis.

Usually, the acceleration of an object whose position is represented by $f(t)$ is identified with $f''(t)$. (Recall $f'(t)$ is the speed.) So in this case, $f''(t)$ would have to be a monotonically decreasing function.

Answer (score 0):

$\ln x$ would be an example, its second derivative is $\frac{-1}{x^2}$.